# Quando o tempo chegar a 0, o button ficar disabled

Tags: php, javascript, html

Bom é o seguinte eu tenho dois ficheiros.

Primeiro Ficheiro (index.php):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Teste</title>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  function numero(a){
   var nun = [];
   nun[0] = -150;
   nun[1] = -750;
   nun[2] = -900;
   nun[3] = -1050;
   nun[4] = -1200;
   nun[5] = -1425;
   nun[6] = -450;
   nun[7] = -600;
   nun[8] = -675;
   nun[9] = -525;
   nun[10] = -375;
   nun[11] = -225;
   nun[12] = -1125;
   nun[13] = -975;
   nun[14] = -825;
   return nun[a];
  }
  function fun(){
 $.ajax({
 url: 'aposta.php',
 success: function(a){
  if(a){
  a = JSON.parse(a);
  $("#tempo").html(a.time);
  $("#box").animate({
    'background-position-x': numero(a.numero)
   },500);
   } else {
   $("#tempo").html("0");
   }
   }
  }); 
 }
  setInterval(function(){
  fun();
  }, 1000);
 </script>
 <style>
 body{
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
 }
 #box{
 max-width: 1125px;
    height: 75px;
 width: 815px;
 background-image: url("http://csgoroulette.blue/templates/1/assets/images/numbers.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
 position: relative;
    margin: 0px auto;
 }
 #ponteiro {
    background-color: #FFFF00;
    margin-left:50%;
    width: 5px;
    height: 75px;
}
#tempo{
 font-size: 28px;
}
 </style>
</head>
<body onload="fun();">
<div id="tempo"></div>
<div id="box"><div id="ponteiro"></div></div><br><br>
<button type="button" >Click Me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Segundo ficheiro (aposta.php):

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Brazil/East');
@set_magic_quotes_runtime(false);
ini_set('magic_quotes_runtime', 0);
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "vertrigo";
$dbname = "csgodouble";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql_aposta = "SELECT id, numero_sorteado, hash, data_f,status FROM apostas where status = '0' ORDER BY status DESC LIMIT 1";
$result_aposta = $conn->query($sql_aposta);
if($result_aposta->num_rows > 0){

 while($row = $result_aposta->fetch_assoc()) {
    $agora = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $soma = strtotime($agora) - strtotime($row['data_f']);
    if($row['data_f'] == 0){
        $sql_aposta = "UPDATE apostas SET data_f='".date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+59 second'))."' WHERE id=".$row['id'];
        $conn->query($sql_aposta);
        exit;
    }else if($soma > 0){
        $sql_aposta = "UPDATE apostas SET status='1' WHERE id=".$row['id'];
        $conn->query($sql_aposta);
        exit;
    }   
    $json_str = array(
    'numero' => $row['numero_sorteado'],
    'hash' => $row['hash'],
    'data_f' => $row['data_f'],
    'time' => abs($soma)
    );

    echo json_encode($json_str);    
 }
}


?>
```

O que queria fazer era, quando o valor de $soma chegasse ao 0, o button no index.php ficava disabled, por 6 segundos, e depois desses 6 segundos voltasse a ficar able e o ciculo repetia-se etc...

Como poderei fazer isso?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu **index.php** deixa a função `fun()` da seguinte maneira:

```
function fun() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'aposta.php',
        success: function(a){
            if(a) {
                a = JSON.parse(a);
                $("#tempo").html(a.time);

                if (a.time === 0) {
                    $('button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('button').removeAttr('disabled');
                    }, 6000);
                }

                $("#box").animate({
                    'background-position-x': numero(a.numero)
                }, 500);
            }
            else {
                $("#tempo").html("0");
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Parte relevante:

```
if (a.time === 0) {
    $('button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('button').removeAttr('disabled');
    }, 6000);
}
```

O `if() {}` vai identificar que **a.time** é igual a `0`, que pelo que identifiquei do seu código em **aposta.php** é o valor de `$soma` que você está interessado.

Se **a.time** for `0` então o botão em **index.php** será desabilitado. Logo em seguida é criado um timeout, o qual vai reabilitar o botão dali 6 segundos.

Comment: Bom é exatamente isto que eu queria, mas diga-me uma coisa, se eu quiser aplicar essa função a 3 butões com ids diferentes como poderei fazer? Tem que ser pela tag button ou pode ser pela id, para não ser obrigatoriamente um button mas sim um input type submit. Obrigado.

Comment: @Gonçalo isso mesmo, se for aplicar para mais botões é só você usar outros seletores, por exemplo a ID: `$('#IDbotaoUm');` e depois `$('#IDbotaoDois');`. Qualquer seletor serve. `$('.classeBotoes');` também.

Comment: Obrigado, a questão foi exclarecida.